# HTML - £ pound symbol from database displayed as ? even with charset=UTF-8

Tags: mysql, html, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

We have a bunch of database data that someone manually entered. They contain a lot of British Pound (£) symbols. The original user copy/pasted the pound sign from somewhere, not sure where (I'm not sure if it matters or not...).

Anyways, when printing out the data on a PHP page, the pound signs appear as the [replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FFFD/index.htm). The page has `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` in it. In the browser, if you change the encoding to `ISO-8859-1`, then the pound signs show up correctly.

After some digging, I've come to the conclusion that the original data entry person copy/pasted an `ISO-8859-1` encoded pound sign into the database. So unless the page is rendered using `ISO-8859-1`, it won't show up correctly.

Here is the header information from Chrome:

```
Request URL:http://www.mysite.com/test.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:X-Mapping-goahf....
Host:www.mysite.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 07 Dec 2011 22:38:14 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Also the MySQL table says it uses `latin1_swedish_ci` which was the default.

So how do I go about fixing this problem? I don't know a lot about how character encoding works and what happens when you copy/paste characters from one place to another.

I tried going to this page:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/browsertest.htm

And copying the pound symbol and pasting it into the database, thinking that would fix it, but it didn't appear to... How do I make the pound symbol that is in the database a UTF-8 pound symbol instead of ISO-8859-1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not matter where the original pound sign was copied from. It does not even matter in what encoding it is stored in the database. The database works on a character level, meaning that if you ask it to store the £ character, it stores the £ character; how exactly that happens behind the scenes and what encoding it's using to do that is an implementation detail that is irrelevant.

What you are missing is that there's a *connection encoding*. When you connect to the database, you are talking to it implicitly or explicitly using a certain character set. That means that any *bytes* you are sending to the database are expected to represent characters in that encoding (so the database knows what characters it's supposedly receiving) and any text data you receive from the database will be encoded in that encoding (so *you* know how you should treat the results). The default for that connection encoding is often the Latin-1  charset (a.k.a. ISO-8859-1). So when you receive the £ sign from the database, it's converting it on-the-fly into Latin-1, whatever encoding it was stored in in the database. So you are receiving the £ sign encoded in Latin-1 and are outputting it as is into your page, but you are specifying to the browser to interpret the page as UTF-8. That of course leads to a misinterpreted character.

You can change the connection defaults in various ways, either in the MySQL configuration, using certain methods in your client library (which you aren't specifying) or by issuing the query `SET NAMES utf8;` after connecting to the database.

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8` worked perfectly. I'm working with a shared database so changing the configuration of MySQL isn't an option. Thanks for the lesson! Also, is there a reason that simply setting my table (or column) collation to `utf8_general_ci` doesn't make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply take raw text in one encoding and use a utf8 meta tag to display it.

I don't know what coding is latin1_swedish_ci but quite possibly it is an alias to iso-8859-1. So either you convert the coding to UTF-8 or you fix the meta tag to show the correct coding.

If you are going to convert it I suggest [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv). You may have to make sure mysql knows the new coding too. Someone else seems to have gone through it at http://drupal.org/node/62258